# What is the rationate behind the choice of StackOverflow date format?

Tags: discussion, questions

Stackoverflow shows date format like below:

**Oct 24 '08 at 5:17**

1. Where the "MMM dd 'yy" date format idea came from?
2. What is the name of the  date format?
3. Is it popular in certain countries or industries?
4. If the answer to #3 is no, then why not just following data format what most users are familiar with?
5. Any option to change the date format to something I am familiar with? (like yyyy-MM-dd)

**[Update]**

I unmarked the answer because after further search, still, I am not able to find any reference to this format.
It seems that the there is a misunderstanding here. I am not questioning [Month, day, year] sequence. That sequence is commonly used.

The laser focus of my question is the use of Apostrophes is the date.

This specific use of Apostrophes is not defined or mentioned in Wikipedia:
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Date_and_time_notation_in_the_United_States#Date

This article suggest a diffrent usage:

The Correct Use of Apostrophes in Dates: https://www.planetquark.com/2011/05/31/the-correct-use-of-apostrophes-in-dates/#.W8kR72hKiHs

[image: The Correct Use of Apostrophes in Dates]

Also, most grammar sites suggest the different use of Apostrophes in dates. Here is an example

https://www.grammarly.com/blog/how-to-write-dates/

So, is there any credible refrence that suggest this date format used in stack overflow: "MMM dd 'yy" (note the Apostrophes before yy)

Also, before you down-vote this question, please consider that by no means this is not about questioning why this format is used and this is not about challenging the date formats in the United States. Not at all.

All I am asking is where the format came from, and do we have a valid link to a reference that mentions the format.

I personally haven't seen this format used in any other website created in or based in United States.

Comment: You should probably split off point number 5 into a separate question, as it is a feature request, while the others are asking for a rationale/information. They don't fit together all that well.

Comment: If you hover over timestamps, you _will_ get that date format you are familiar with.

Comment: An apostrophe to indicate omission is a writing style that English speakers use every day, like "I'm" for "I am".

Comment: @HansPassant: some "English speakers" use something else they are familiar with. [Example of several thousands of em](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=im+dont+doesnt). Must be a coincidence that practically *all* have pretty low scores.

Comment: @usr2564301 weird how elasticsearch recognizes plural forms of words but not a missing apostrophe.

Comment: For your updated question, since you only want to focus on the use of the apostrophe, is off-topic here and should be asked on ELL, which already has a question there: *[When did the the apostrophe become common for shortening the Year in a date?](https://english.stackexchange.com/q/118754/10500)*

Comment: @Kendra, the solution "hover over all dates to see what they mean" is about the worst possible solution ever suggested for anything, ever. It's actually much worse than the OP says because sometimes the year is omitted entirely. Outside of USA I can't imagine anyone would read "May 10" as "tenth of may 2019" (ie 2019-5-10) but rather as May 2010. It's such a weird format to use when much clearer more scannable formats are available.

Comment: @pbhj 1) I was offering a workaround, not an answer. Hence, a comment, not an answer. I didn't make the site, therefore I am not the one to argue about why it was written that way with. 2) This post is several months old at this point. I really don't care. 3) If you want to argue that the date display should be changed, research on Meta to see if/how others have proposed it, I guarantee they have, and why their proposals have failed, then decide if yours would be a duplicate before you decide if you should post your own proposal.

Comment: It wasn't an attack on you; obviously 'solutions' are constrained by the site code. FWIW I've used a [userContent.css on Firefox to fix it for me](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/385090/383694). Per (2) the problem is older than that, and still a problem. The other proposals appear to have failed because whoever controls the site dev has a personal preference for USA styled dates and doesn't care to give a preference for the rest of the World; you're right it's pretty futile to argue with that sort of position.

Comment: I'm really surprised that it's still not possible to change the date format, especially now that the US only accounts for around 30% of the user base:

https://devbizops.medium.com/most-active-countries-on-stack-overflow-def3360c6d10

Answer (score 1):

That shorthand is a common way to refer to dates in the United States, where Stack Overflow is primarily based.  It's unlikely to change, although you could create a feature request explaining *why* it should; most international users of the site haven't had much of an issue with it as far as I can tell.

Comment: Thank you for help. What is the name of the format?

Comment: I've never known this format to have a name before...

Comment: @Makoto the "correct" format

Comment: @KevinB you mean the "I wanna stand out from everyone else" format

Comment: @Epodax By definition, to be better, you must be different

Comment: I'm not sure the Imperial system agrees @KevinB

Comment: So the point is @KevinB to add friction to date reading, making the dates stand out as different and not fit in to any established system. Great, unless you want good UX of course, then it's abysmal.

Comment: I'm really surprised that it's still not possible to change the date format, especially now that the US only accounts for around 30% of the user base:

https://devbizops.medium.com/most-active-countries-on-stack-overflow-def3360c6d10

Comment: @IODEV:  But the team is also based in the US and the team works with predominately US clients.  Again, I'm not seeing much in the way of any international users having an *issue* with this so I don't see the value in addressing a nonexistent issue.

Comment: @Makoto: Well, in my opinion that is a very selfish way to address it. Sadly. That US team works with predominantly US based clients is just irrelevant and also not true nowadays.

Comment: @IODEV:  When it actually becomes a problem that's expensive enough to deal with, it can be dealt with at that time.  That's a principle of software development, *especially* since we know how resource-strapped the Stack Overflow development team always is.  I don't disagree that it'd be good for UX, but "good for UX" doesn't always indicate that it is a top priority.