# Allow user to set their own regional settings

Tags: feature-request, profile-page

One thing I struggle with in SO is the bias of writing dates in US format.  I live in the UK and instead of using the format "MMM dd 'yy" (e.g. "Jul 18 '19") I would prefer "dd/MM/yyyy" or "dd MMM yyyyy".  I always trip up when trying to interpret a US date which is a distraction.  As a software developer even the ISO 8601 "yyyy-MM-dd" format would be far better as I use this often and it is unambiguous.

Would it be hard to allow a user to set some regional settings in their profile and then render out dates, numbers etc in their preferred format?

Comment: There are some user scripts that do this, see https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/288674/custom-date-format.

Comment: In general if you mouseover datetimes in SO, the tooltip is an ISO-like format - e.g. for this question's posting time `2020-08-27 09:21:32Z`, as I write this last edit time `2020-08-27 09:42:31Z`.

Comment: By "regional settings", did you mean only the number format, or also the locale/language? The former might be complex enough if we want to support all countries. The latter doesn't worth the developer's resource.

Comment: @AndrewT I was only looking for dates in particular (although the wide date and number formats would make sense).  I see language as a separate matter.

Comment: The best SO can do is format using [`toLocaleString()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/toLocaleString), which will use whatever the browser thinks is your locale format, which may or may not match the format you've set in your OS. Sure, they could also provide a preference in your profile where you could set your preferred date and time formats, but they've generally avoided adding preferences like the plague.